# Navbar on Slanted Div

Tags: html, css

I have created a slated div to use with my navbar, but it messes up the rest of the formatting for the website. The navbar is in the top right and the slanted div is underneath it, but it messes up everything else on the webpage. I've been trying everything to no avail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Mp3.jpg

Navbar HTML:

```
<template name="navbar">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.meteor.com/try">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://guide.meteor.com">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://docs.meteor.com">Experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://forums.meteor.com" class="active">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Navbar CSS:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0em 0em 1em 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
}

.navbar:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg);
  transform: skew(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  z-index: -1;
}

li {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 2em;
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0.5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: white;
  transition: background 0.2s ease,
              padding 0.8s linear;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

"Bobcats Services" Div HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    {{> navbar}}
  </div>
  <div id="center">
      <h1>Bobcats Services</h1>
      <h2>Everything you need!</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

"Bobcats Services" Div CSS:

```
/* CSS declarations go here */
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /*background-color: #0193ff;*/

  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#00b7ea+0,009ec3+100;Blue+3D+%2315 */
  background: rgb(135,224,253); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(83,203,241,1) 40%, rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(83,203,241,1) 40%,rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%,rgba(83,203,241,1) 40%,rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

  /* Image instead of standard color
  background-image: url("images/watch-plane.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  */
}

#nav {

}

#center {
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #008fc8;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure i completely understand the problem. What is the problem, how it messes up with the page? Where you want to be the navigation and where you want the content squared by you? A live example could help as well.

Comment: @ValentinVrinceanu Yea, the thing that says Bobcats Services is supposed to be further down, which I gave it the margin-top, but seems to completely ignore it.

Comment: Please share the html and css for "the thing" that says Bobcats Services

Comment: @ValentinVrinceanu Added to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using float, you need to clear, so the folllowing elements to look right. I have added here: https://jsfiddle.net/44x11g34/ an example.

What i had added between the 2 main blocks:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and some small css

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Hope this will help you.